# CSS how to postiton div outside main container without it moving over the container on window re-size?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a sharebox(div containing social site links) that I've been using with a fixed position outside the main container. I realized that when I re-size the browser window by dragging the border it causes my sharebox div to move over the top of the container.

I looked through related posts here but don't think they apply to this so sorry if I missed it somewhere.

Here is an example of the problem: http://metrotechpc.net/test/positionedbox.html

Is there a way, preferably with pure css(no javascript) to make the div stay away from the container on browser window re-size so the user has to scroll over to see it?

I've tried giving it padding, margin, different positions(absolute and fixed).

I am actually inserting this code into the top of the page with genisis_hook function on a wordpress page so that may be an issue but getting it to work in a basic html like the example link would be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your CSS:

1. There's a typo in the rule for `#container`: `postition: relative;` instead of `position: relative;`
2. You should move the sharebox div inside the container div.
3. Add `position: absolute` to the sharebox div's CSS and then specify `right: 70px` to make it start from the right border.

Lastly, there's another typo in the sharebox's CSS: `margin: left:20px;` instead of `margin-left: 20px`

Comment: thanks for pointing out my typos Gabriele,

Comment: Sorry about those. I was rushing to make an example. Fixing the position typo on the container strangely caused the sharebox to move under container rather than over it which is better. But what I'm trying to do is have it outside the container. Won't putting it inside the container make it position based on the borders of the container? I want to position it based on the borders of the browser window so it will stay away from content.

Comment: OK Gabriele, I think I figured it out. I put the sharebox inside the container as you said, and then I used right:0px to position it at the border of the container and then used negative margin to push it outside the container and now it stays out when the window is resized like it should. Feel free to let me know if this is bad practice. Thanks so much.

Comment: You could also use right: -70px which looks like a better solution (should push it out of the container entirely)

Comment: oops I just realized, this stops it from staying in place with vertical scrolling which was part of the reason for positioning it based on the window rather than the container. That way it stays in place while the content scrolls. I know there is a javascript for this but was trying to avoid using javascript. I guess I'm going to need to use a script version and a noscript version unless there is a way in css. The top position needs to be based on the window so it stays 100px off the top of the window when the rest of the content scrolls.

Comment: Yeah here's a live example of another site. http://mashable.com/2011/07/09/gadgets-driving-crashes/ They have a javascript version and a noscript version. I can do that with some time to work out the script. With it inside the container they actually resize the div so it turns into a bar over the article instead of disappearing off the page which is really cool feature.